# Loading Adult Dataset from file to Database

Tags: sql, postgresql, dataset, plpgsql

I've created some basics aggregate, and I'd would like to test them out.
I'd like to work with an Adult Dataset, imported from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/adult this link.
I've created the table, that can contain the data, but I'm not able to upload it (the file is **adult test**).
Any way to do it?

I've opened the file in notepad++, inserted quotes on the string type values, but there are 39K rows.
I can't type for 39K times **INSERT INTO**.

Any Help?

Comment: Save the data into a file and use `copy`.

Comment: "Adult Dataset", was hesitant to click on link from work...

Comment: *"I can't type ..."* - Notepad++ also supports macro's that can help you with that, if you can't or won't use any bulk-import feature (which I guess exist for PostgreSQL as well as any other database).

Comment: @GolezTrol Do you know how to type INSERT INTO **JUST BEFORE** the first number in notepad++?

Answer (score 2):

In Notepad++ with the file open, use regex replace to create the statement. Bear in mind it's *much* faster to do a single INSERT, rather than creating a new INSERT statement for every one of the 32k+ rows.

On `adult.data`, using the first 5 rows as example:

```
39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
50, Self-emp-not-inc, 83311, Bachelors, 13, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 13, United-States, <=50K
38, Private, 215646, HS-grad, 9, Divorced, Handlers-cleaners, Not-in-family, White, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
53, Private, 234721, 11th, 7, Married-civ-spouse, Handlers-cleaners, Husband, Black, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
28, Private, 338409, Bachelors, 13, Married-civ-spouse, Prof-specialty, Wife, Black, Female, 0, 0, 40, Cuba, <=50K
```

Replace -> Search Mode: Regular Expression

Find what: `^([^,]+), ([^,]+), ([^,]+), ([^,]+), ([^,]+), ([^,]+), ([^,]+), ([^,]+), ([^,]+), ([^,]+), ([^,]+), ([^,]+), ([^,]+), ([^,]+), ([^,]+)$`

Replace with: `\($1, '$2', $3, '$4', $5, '$6', '$7', '$8', '$9', '$10', $11, $12, $13, '$14', '$15'\),`

Hit `Replace All`

```
(39, 'State-gov', 77516, 'Bachelors', 13, 'Never-married', 'Adm-clerical', 'Not-in-family', 'White', 'Male', 2174, 0, 40, 'United-States', '<=50K'),
(50, 'Self-emp-not-inc', 83311, 'Bachelors', 13, 'Married-civ-spouse', 'Exec-managerial', 'Husband', 'White', 'Male', 0, 0, 13, 'United-States', '<=50K'),
(38, 'Private', 215646, 'HS-grad', 9, 'Divorced', 'Handlers-cleaners', 'Not-in-family', 'White', 'Male', 0, 0, 40, 'United-States', '<=50K'),
(53, 'Private', 234721, '11th', 7, 'Married-civ-spouse', 'Handlers-cleaners', 'Husband', 'Black', 'Male', 0, 0, 40, 'United-States', '<=50K'),
(28, 'Private', 338409, 'Bachelors', 13, 'Married-civ-spouse', 'Prof-specialty', 'Wife', 'Black', 'Female', 0, 0, 40, 'Cuba', '<=50K'),
```

Now you just stick an `INSERT INTO your_table (columns...) VALUES` at the top of the file, delete any trailing comma at the bottom of the file, and you're sorted.